# How to set Object Value as Variable and not as String in JavaScript/React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object

In React & Js I am saving an Input Name as a String in an Object :

```
window.ObjectOne = {
  ObjectOneKey : "MyInputName",
}
```

The Input Name is an **Object Path** Like "**Object.FirstName**" or a **Variable Name** "**MyVariableName**"

What I am Trying is to save the inpute name **AS a Variable** or **Object Path**, not as a String (Without Quote) like this :

```
window.ObjectOne = {
  ObjectOneKey : MyInputName,
}
```

What I want is to EXPORT this Object with Variable Name as Object Value to import it in another project/website... This way, Objects will always have VariableName as value to refer Localproject Variable (Easier to Edit One Variable value than Multiple Object Value)

Is there a Way to do it ? Tried to replace Quote in Object value but it's not working

Comment: Where does `MyInputName` variable come from? What's its value?

Comment: Value is Store in a window.Object or a window.Variable and it's always a string (Name, First Name etc...)

But Maybe I am wrong. Maybe I just have to create a TextArea or a Div wich look like an Object and Export This

Comment: Side note: Although you can do what you like in your own code, the overwhelmingly-common convention in JavaScript is that only constructor functions are written with a capital first letter. So `myInputName`, `objectOne`, `objectOneKey`, etc. would be the usual thing. You don't have to follow standard practice in your own code, but doing so makes it easier for people to read and understand (and help with) your code.

Comment: This sounds like [an X/Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). With a better idea what problem you're trying to solve by doing this, we can probably suggest a better way to do it.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yes Thanks, Sorry for convention error

Yes, maybe I misspoke about my problem.

I want to export a javascript Object with Keys => Values ​​but so that the values ​​are variable names or paths for objects (not the result of the variable itself). I want to export this Object to import it into another project which will have the same variable names. But it looks like the Javascript object still displays the contents of the variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I **think** you're asking how to make sure that `ObjectOne.ObjectOneKey` always provides the **current** value of `MyInputName`, which is declared and updated elsewhere in the code, like this:

```
let MyInputName = "something";
// ...
MyInputName = "something else";
```

If so, you have to make `ObjectOneKey` an accessor property, like this:

```
window.ObjectOne = {
    get ObjectOneKey() { return MyInputName; }
};
```

Then, whenever you access `ObjectOne.ObjectOneKey`, you'll get the current value of `MyInputName`, even if it's changed since the object was created.

Live Example:

```js
let MyInputName = "something";
window.ObjectOne = {
    get ObjectOneKey() { return MyInputName; }
};

// Just add an ever-increasing number to `MyInputName`:
let n = 1;
setInterval(() => {
    MyInputName = "something" + (n++);
}, 10);

document.querySelector("input[type=button]").addEventListener("click", () => {
    console.log(ObjectOne.ObjectOneKey);
});
```

```html
Every time you click this button, you'll see a different value.
<input type="button" value="Show ObjectOne.ObjectOneKey">
```

---

That said, this is unlikely to be the best way to go about doing this. In modern environments, you can use JavaScript standard modules ("ESM") and just export `MyInputName`. Exports are live bindings in ESM, so every time a module uses its imported version of `MyInputName`, it sees the current value of the one in the original module, even if it's been changed.

For instance, suppose you have `inputs.js`:

```
// Export `myValue`
export let myValue = 0;
// Add to it every 10ms
setInterval(() => {
    ++myValue;
}, 10);
```

...and you have `App.tsx` importing and using `myValue` like this:

```
// ...
import { myValue } from "./inputs.js";

export default function App() {
    const onClick = () => {
        console.log(myValue);
    };
    return (
        <div>
            <input type="button" value="Click To See `myValue`" onClick={onClick} />
            <p>
                Click the button above and look in the console. You'll see a different number each
                time (unless you) click <strong>really</strong> quickly.
            </p>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Every click will see the then-current value of `myValue`. Live example on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ye5vex?file=src%2FApp.js,src%2Finputs.js).

Comment: Seems to be a Good way to achieve what I want to do ! 

Thanks for help